# How can I pass a symbolic argument/function to Findroot or NDSolve and force them to not be evaluated until a numeric value is inputted?

Tags: list-manipulation, differential-equations, equation-solving

I have a 35X35 symbolic matrix that I would like to calculate the determinant of.  With that being said, it takes way too long.  As it is eventually going to be an equation in a system I feed to NDSolve, I was considering forcing it to be unevaluated until NDSolve takes it and "plugs" numbers in.  Can someone tell me if this is possible with Mathematica?

My current implementation takes a system h(x)=0 and joins this system with $det\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}==0$ and attempts to solve using findroot.
Call $det\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}=A$. Then with IC equal to an inital guess of solutions, I use

```
ndet[A_ /; MatrixQ[A, NumericQ]] := Det[N[A]];
sol = FindRoot[
  Join[h, {ndet[A]}] , IC]
```

As A is the determinant of a large (35x35) and symbolic matrix, I would like to only calculate A when the function Findroot is plugging in numbers.

I have a similar issue later on in the same code using the NDSolve, which I will omit here as the problem is similar.

As a side note, the findroot solution is used as an inital condition for a nonlinear differential-algabraic system later on.

Here is a workable snippet of the code up to FindRoot solution

```
(*enter parameters here*)
mug = 0.05;(*Jgenerator/Ms/R^2*)
Ms = 362.7;
Mus = 40;
u = Mus/Ms;(*mus/ms*)
V = 22.352;(*m/s driving speed*)
kt = 182087;(*tire stiffness*)
ks = 20053;(*suspension stiffness*)
omegac = 2*Pi*V*.005;
omega0 = Sqrt[ks/Ms];
omegat = Sqrt[kt/Ms];
vc = omegac/omega0;
v = omegat/omega0;
gr = .1617035985;(*road roughness*)
R = .03/2/Pi;
d = .01^2*7/omega0^2/R^2;(*2piGrV/omega0^2/R^2*)
mur = .1;(*maximize mur at .2 for compactness*)
cm = 148;(*mechanical damping in Ns/m*)
para = {\[Mu]r -> mur, xi -> cm/2/omega0/Ms, \[Mu]g -> mug};
(*\[Phi]0+\[Phi] expansion after M^-1. \
x[1]=\[Theta];x[2]=\[Phi];x[3]=\[CapitalPsi]s;x[4]=\[CapitalPsi]us*)
m[1, 1] = 1 + \[Mu]g + \[Mu]r*(1 + \[Eta]^2 + 2*\[Eta]*Cos[x[2]]);
m[1, 2] = \[Mu]r*\[Eta]*(\[Eta] + Cos[x[2]]) - \[Mu]g;
m[1, 3] = 1;
m[1, 4] = 0;
m[2, 1] = m[1, 2];
m[2, 2] = \[Mu]r*\[Eta]^2 + \[Mu]g;
m[2, 3] = 0;
m[2, 4] = 0;
m[3, 1] = 1;
m[3, 2] = 0;
m[3, 3] = 1 + u;
m[3, 4] = 0;
m[4, 1] = 0;
m[4, 2] = 0;
m[4, 3] = 0;
m[4, 4] = 0;


(*mass,damping,stiffness matrix*)
M = {{m[1, 1], m[1, 2], m[1, 3], m[1, 4]}, {m[2, 1], m[2, 2], m[2, 3],
     m[2, 4]}, {m[3, 1], m[3, 2], m[3, 3], m[3, 4]}, {m[4, 1], 
    m[4, 2], m[4, 3], m[4, 4]}};
Dm = {{2*(xi + xie), -2 xie, 0, 0}, {-2 xie, 2*xie, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
    0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}};
K = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, u*v^2, -u*v^2}, {0, 0, 0, vc}};

(*external and nonlinear force*)
Force = {\[Mu]r*\[Eta]*x[4]*(2*x[3] + x[4])*Sin[x[2]], -\[Mu]r*\[Eta]*
    x[3]^2*Sin[x[2]], 0, n};

(*substitute in harmonic functions*)

EOM = (M . {x'[5], x'[6], x'[7], 0} + Dm . {x[5], x[6], x[7], x'[4]} +
    K . {x[1], x[2], x[3], x[4]} - Force)

sol = Solve[{EOM[[1]] == 0, EOM[[2]] == 0, EOM[[3]] == 0, 
   EOM[[4]] == 0}, {x'[4], x'[5], x'[6], x'[7]}]



EQ[1] = x'[5] /. sol[[1]];
EQ[2] = x'[6] /. sol[[1]];
EQ[3] = x'[7] /. sol[[1]];
EQ[4] = x'[4] /. sol[[1]];



eq[1] = (EQ[1] /. 
     x[2] -> \[Phi]0) + (D[EQ[1], x[2]] /. x[2] -> \[Phi]0)*x[2];
eq[2] = (EQ[2] /. 
     x[2] -> \[Phi]0) + (D[EQ[2], x[2]] /. x[2] -> \[Phi]0)*x[2];
eq[3] = (EQ[3] /. 
     x[2] -> \[Phi]0) + (D[EQ[3], x[2]] /. x[2] -> \[Phi]0)*x[2];
eq[4] = (EQ[4] /. 
     x[2] -> \[Phi]0) + (D[EQ[4], x[2]] /. x[2] -> \[Phi]0)*x[2];
(*drift coefficients as a vector*)
A = {x[5], x[6], x[7], eq[1], eq[2], eq[3], eq[4]} /. 
    n -> 0 /. -1 - \[Mu]r + \[Mu]r*Cos[\[Phi]0]^2 -> -1 - \[Mu]r*
      Sin[\[Phi]0]^2;
\[CapitalSigma] = {0, 0, 0, Coefficient[eq[1], n]*Sqrt[d], 
    Coefficient[eq[2], n]*Sqrt[d], Coefficient[eq[3], n]*Sqrt[d], 
    Coefficient[eq[4], n]*
     Sqrt[d]} /. -1 - \[Mu]r + \[Mu]r*Cos[\[Phi]0]^2 -> -1 - \[Mu]r*
      Sin[\[Phi]0]^2;
Col = Outer[Times, \[CapitalSigma], \[CapitalSigma]];
numstates = 7;(*number of state variable eqns*)

(*moment differential equations w/cumulant neglect*)(*define two \
differential operators here*)

D1[f_, i_] := D[f, x[i]];
D2[f_, i_, j_] := D[f, {x[i], 1}, {x[j], 1}];

(*g:moment generating function*)
g[i_, j_, k_, n_, z_, y_, q_] = 
  x[7]^i*x[6]^{j - i}*x[5]^{k - j}*x[4]^{n - k}*x[3]^{z - n}*
   x[2]^{y - z}*x[1]^{q - y};

(*generate a list of moments up to h-th order*)
G = Flatten[
   Table[g[i, j, k, n, z, y, q], {q, 1, 2}, {y, 0, q}, {z, 0, y}, {n, 
     0, z}, {k, 0, n}, {j, 0, k}, {i, 0, j}]];


(*define two Gaussian closure functions*)
GClosure1[i_, j_, 
   k_] := \[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     j*k] + \[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     i*k] + \[CapitalEpsilon][k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][i*j] - 
   2*\[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][k];
GClosure2[i_, j_, k_, 
   l_] := \[CapitalEpsilon][i*j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     k*l] + \[CapitalEpsilon][i*k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     j*l] + \[CapitalEpsilon][i*l]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j*k] - 
   2*\[CapitalEpsilon][i]*\[CapitalEpsilon][j]*\[CapitalEpsilon][
     k]*\[CapitalEpsilon][l];


(*close 3rd and 4th order moments with 1st and 2nd moments using \
Gaussian closure*)
subs1 = Flatten[
   Table[x[i]*x[j]*x[k] -> GClosure1[x[i], x[j], x[k]], {i, 1, 7}, {j,
      1, 7}, {k, 1, 7}]];
subs2 = Flatten[
   Table[x[i]*x[j]*x[k]*x[l] -> GClosure2[x[i], x[j], x[k], x[l]], {i,
      1, 7}, {j, 1, 7}, {k, 1, 7}, {l, 1, 7}]];

(*SUBs applies in order subs2,subs1,and Table[G[[i]]\[Rule]\
\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]],{i,Length[G],1,-1}].The last substitutes \
\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] for G[[i]],where \[CapitalEpsilon][] \
denotes expected values*)
SUBs = Join[subs2, subs1, 
   Table[G[[i]] -> \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]], {i, Length[G], 1, -1}]];

(*moment equations.\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]]\[Rule]y[i][t] \
substitutes state variables y[i][t] for \[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]]*)
SME = Flatten[
    Expand[Table[-Sum[D1[G[[i]], j]*A[[j]], {j, 1, numstates}] - 
        1/2*
         Sum[D2[G[[i]], j, k]*Col[[j, k]], {j, 1, numstates}, {k, 1, 
           numstates}], {i, 1, Length[G]}]] /. SUBs] /. 
   Table[\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] -> y[i], {i, 1, Length[G]}];

Table[\[CapitalEpsilon][G[[i]]] -> y[i], {i, 1, Length[G]}]
SME2 = SME /. Table[y[i] -> 0, {i, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12}}];
y8sub = Flatten[Solve[{SME2[[11]] == 0}(*/.\[Phi]0->0*), {y[8]}]] // 
  Simplify
y27sub = Flatten[Solve[{SME2[[27]] == 0}(*/.\[Phi]0->0*), {y[27]}]] //
   Simplify
y10sub = Flatten[Solve[{SME2[[22]] == 0}(*/.\[Phi]0->0*), {y[10]}]] //
   Simplify
y11sub = Flatten[Solve[SME2[[14]] == 0, y[11]]] // Simplify;
SME`simplifieda = 
  SME /. y8sub /. y11sub /. {y[13] -> -y[18]} /. 
    Table[y[i] -> 0, {i, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12}}] // Simplify;
y29sub = Flatten[
  Solve[SME`simplifieda[[Length[SME`simplifieda]]] == 0, y[29]]]
SME`simplifieda = SME`simplifieda /. y29sub

(*SME`simplifieda=SME/.y8sub/.y11sub/.y29sub/.{y[13]->-y[18]}/.Table[\
y[i]->0,{i,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12}}]//Simplify;*)
remaining = SparseArray[SME`simplifieda]["NonzeroPositions"] // Flatten
(*SME`simplified=SME/.y8sub/.y11sub/.y29sub/.{y[13]->-y[18]}/.Table[y[\
i]->0,{i,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12}}];
SME`simplified=SME`simplified[[remaining]]*)
SME`simplified = SME`simplifieda[[remaining]]
Dimensions[%]
vars = Join[Table[y[i][\[Eta]], {i, 9, 10}], 
  Table[y[i][\[Eta]], {i, 14, 28}], 
  Table[y[i][\[Eta]], {i, 30, Length[SME]}], {\[Phi]0[\[Eta]]}]
Length[vars]
varsd = D[vars, \[Eta]];
subs = Join[
   Table[y[i] -> y[i][\[Eta]], {i, 1, 
     Length[SME]}], {\[Phi]0 -> \[Phi]0[\[Eta]]}];
AE = SME`simplified /. para /. subs;
AE2 = AE /. \[Phi]0[\[Eta]] -> 0
remainingAE = SparseArray[AE2]["NonzeroPositions"] // Flatten;
AE = AE[[remainingAE]]
Dimensions[%]
tt = Table[
     Coefficient[D[AE, \[Eta]][[i]], varsd[[j]]], {i, 1, 
      Length[vars]}, {j, 1, Length[vars]}] /. 
    Join[Table[
      y[i][\[Eta]] -> y[i], {i, 1, 
       35}], {\[Phi]0[\[Eta]] -> \[Phi]0}] /. \[Phi]0 -> 0 // Simplify
SparseArray[tt]["NonzeroPositions"]
SparseArray[tt]["AdjacencyLists"]
(*tt=Grad[SME[[1;;Length[SME]]],Delete[Join[Table[y[i],{i,1,Length[\
SME]}],{\[Phi]0}],2]]/.Table[y[i]\[Rule]0,{i,{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,12}}]/.\
Join[Table[y[i][\[Eta]]\[Rule]y[i],{i,1,35}],{\[Phi]0[\[Eta]]\[Rule]\
\[Phi]0}]/.para/.\[Phi]0\[Rule]0//Simplify*)
ndet[A_ /; MatrixQ[A, NumericQ]] := Det[N[A]];

(*d`AE=Det[tt]//Simplify*)
BF = AE /. 
     Join[Table[
       y[i][\[Eta]] -> y[i], {i, 1, 
        35}], {\[Phi]0[\[Eta]] -> \[Phi]0}] /. para /. \[Phi]0 -> 0;
remainingBF = SparseArray[BF]["NonzeroPositions"] // Flatten;
BF = BF[[remainingBF]] // Simplify;





Eqn = Join[BF(*,{d`AE}*)]
Length[Eqn]

vars2 = Join[Table[y[i], {i, 9, 10}], Table[y[i], {i, 14, 28}], 
  Table[y[i], {i, 30, Length[SME]}]]
Length[%]


IC = Join[
  Table[{vars2[[i]], .1}, {i, 1, 
    Length[vars2]}], {{xie, .1, .00000001, 10}}]
\[Eta]0 = .9;
sol = FindRoot[
  Join[Eqn[[1 ;; Length[Eqn]]], {Det[
      tt]}] /. {\[Eta] -> \[Eta]0, \[Phi]0 -> 0}, IC, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 14, PrecisionGoal -> 14]
Table[sol[[i]], {i, 1, Length[sol]}];
ICond = Join[% /. 
    Rule[x_, z_] -> x[0] == z, {\[Eta][0] == \[Eta]0}] /. 
  Table[y[i] -> ToExpression[StringJoin["y", ToString[i]]], {i, 1, 
    35}]
```

Edit;
I have just edited my code snippet as there was a missing line

Comment: Define a new function whose arguments are protected by `?NumericQ`. See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/26037/4999 for links to examples.

Comment: @MichaelE2 please see my edit, but I thought I did do that and it did not work at least for FindRoot.

Comment: @JAC I don't see what you mean by joining `h` to a `ndet[A]`, which should be just a number, and feeding that to `FindRoot`. Please include all the definitions necessary to run your code, e.g. `h`, `IC`. Our perplexity comes from the fact that the direct answer to the question in your comment is undoubtedly `NumericQ`, which you say you have already tried; so I suspect other problems.

Comment: @MarcoB my h is a system of 35 non-linear equations. ndet[A] is meant to give the determinant of the jacobian of this set of equations. Thus, I should then have 36 equations. I use FindRoot to  solve this system equal to zero.

Comment: I have added a snippet of my code.  I have attempted to reduce the system

Comment: OP, as I understand it, your attempt to use the suggestion of the other commenters is not as suggested. You’ve attempted to use a `Condition`, whereas a `PatternTest` is what was suggested.